# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'. Try defining the operator '[]'.dart(undefined_operator)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

I am getting this error in my code and I have tried putting data()
Code:

```
body: new Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: new LinearGradient(
      colors: [gradientStart, gradientEnd],
      begin: const FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.0),
      end: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.5),
      stops: [0.0, 1.0],
    )),
    child: new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new Card(
          elevation: 0.0,
          color: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.1),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: new Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new CircleAvatar(
                      child: new Text(snapshot[index].data["title"][0]), //error
                      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    new SizedBox(
                      width: 6.0,
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      width: 210.0,
                      child: new Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new InkWell(
                            child: new Text(
                              snapshot[index].data["title"],  //error
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 22.0, color: Colors.white),
                              maxLines: 1,
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              passData(snapshot[index]);
                            },
                          ),
                          new SizedBox(
                            height: 5.0,
                          ),
                          new Text(
                            snapshot[index].data["content"],//error
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white70),
                            maxLines: 2,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ])),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

I am not able to solve this error in my application. I have 3 errors in title i tried adding () brackets or ? but didn't work. And same for content i used this.content but it gives me error in the [] brackets. Please look after my code and give some possible solutions.

Comment: What is snapshot refers, Can you give some details about this ?

Comment: Please provide more context. I'm not sure what type the `snapshot` is. Is this a `FutureBuilder` or something else?

Comment: Without knowing what your snapshot is, try putting index after data and not before. Also consider omitting the unnecessary new keyword that clutters up the code and does nothing of value.